# Parse text file into structure

Tags: matlab, parsing, text, structure

For some purposes, I wanna give an external text file as input of one of my `MATLAB` functions.

Generally this text file shows the following layout:

```
-----------------------------------------------------

HubHt = 90;
GridWidth = 220;
GridHeight = 220;
Ny = 35;
Nz = 37;
Nfft = 8192;
time = 620;
Uhub = 15;
Coherence = Bladed;

-----------------------------------------------------
```

To read it in, I'm currently calling this piece of code:

```
fid = fopen('test.inp','r+');
A = textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter',';','commentStyle', '-','CollectOutput',1);
fclose(fid);
A = A{1};
inputs = regexp(A,' = ','split');
```

The last variable, `inputs` results in a `<9x1>` cell; each element will be a `<1x2>` cell.

The first element of the `<1x2>` cell is supposed to be the field of a overall INPUT structure, whereas the second element is the associated parameter.

At the moment, I'm using a quite static and awful way to achieve my goal:

```
inp = struct(char(inputs{1}(1)),str2double(inputs{1}(2)),char(inputs{2}(1)),str2double(inputs{2}(2)),char(inputs{3}(1)),str2double(inputs{3}(2)),char(inputs{4}(1)),str2double(inputs{4}(2)),char(inputs{5}(1)),str2double(inputs{5}(2)),char(inputs{6}(1)),str2double(inputs{6}(2)),char(inputs{7}(1)),str2double(inputs{7}(2)),char(inputs{8}(1)),str2double(inputs{8}(2)),char(inputs{9}(1)),char(inputs{9}(2)));
```

I believe that exist quite better ways to do the same: I'd like if you could share one with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cell2struct`:

```
% create cell vector where fieldnames and values alternate
tmp = [inputs{:}];

inp =  cell2struct(tmp(2:2:end), tmp (1:2:end), 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since what you have written is (nearly) valid Matlab source code why not give it the file extension `.m` and just run it ?  Or call it from inside your function.

This is is an approach which we've used a lot; it's straightforward and simple.  Obviously you have to make sure that it is (entirely) valid Matlab source but that's not difficult.